# Run exe silently in deployment

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to build a package and deploy it silently. I have the script ready executing an exe silently, however since the exe uninstalls a program, I still see the window "Configuring..." pop up. I am using

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run("Uninstaller.exe 0,true)
```

This is working fine, as in it's running the uninstaller silently, however once the uninstaller starts doing its job, another window pops up saying "configuring *application name*". Is there a way to hide that?

Comment: Try running `uninstaller /?` and see if you get some usage information out of it, perhaps including an option for silent uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the window you are seeing is part of the .EXE you're running.

Perhaps the "Uninstaller.exe" has a switch or parameter to make it run silently?

### EDIT

If you can use a 3rd party tool, [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site) provides an easy way to hide a window. Look at the [WinSetState](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetState.htm) function.

Comment: I second this. There is very likely a silent switch. If not, you *might* have luck using psexec to run the exe in a session that's not visible to the user.

Comment: you are correct, and no unfortunately it doesnt provide a parameter for a silent install. Im assuming theres a way to hide a window based on the window title? Maybe thats my only choice?